# What is the meaning of "perhaps not surprisingly"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

***Perhaps*** is used when one does not wish to be too definite or assertive in the expression of an opinion.

> "**perhaps not surprisingly**, he was cautious about committing himself"

But, what is the meaning of the phrase *perhaps not surprisingly* in the above sentence? I hope you will give another usage example.

Answer (score 3):

I take it that you understand that *surprisingly*, set in front of the main clause and separated from it with a comma, modifies the entire main clause:

> **Surprisingly**, he was cautious about committing himself *is equivalent to*
>   **It is surprising that** he was cautious about committing himself.

*Perhaps* and *not* modify *surprisingly*:

> **Perhaps not surprisingly**, ... *is equivalent to*
>   **Perhaps it is not surprising that**...

This might be said, for instance, if an ordinarily bold man were unusually cautious in some particular circumstance. At first thought this would surprise you; but thinking more deeply might suggest a possible reason for his caution, and you would realize that **perhaps** you should **not** be surprised.